# Why is LoadLibrary failing in some machines when calling a dll using P/Invoke?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, pinvoke

I have a .NET application that calls a C++ API using P/Invoke. The C++ dll has a dependency from a third-party dll. That third party dll calls `LoadLibrary` to dynamically load libeay32.dll, an OpenSSL dependency.

After doing several tests I found out that the .NET application works correctly in Windows 10 but fails in some deployments using Windows 7. The cause of the failure is because the .NET process is not loading libeay32.dll. I tried placing libeay32.dll in the same directory as the process and in the System folder (having in mind the Dynamically load search order) but the failure persisted in Windows 7 32 bits only. Furthermore, if I called the API dll from a C++ console application it worked without issues in all platforms. To solve the problem I called `LoadLibrary` in the .NET application, before making the P/Invoke calls to the C++ API, and it worked in all target platforms (Windows 10/7 32 and 64 bits).

Why would `LoadLibrary` fail to load libeay32.dll in Windows 7 but not Windows 10 if called from the C++ dll dependency of the API called using P/Invoke?

**Edit**
Some notes from comments:

1. All the compiled assemblies are targeted for x86 architecture.
2. Before posting the question, I verified that no dependencies files
   where missing, using dependency walker.

Comment: Well, what is the error code returned when LoadLibrary fails?

Comment: Can't get the error code because LoadLibrary is called in a third-party dll and I don't have access to the source code.

Comment: Well, that makes this a non question. You are asking about code we can't see.

Comment: Is it possible that the search path is different when the dll is loaded from the .Net app rather than the dependency?

Comment: If you're comfy with setting up quick DLL test projects I'd first establish that I can load the darn thing in a native C++ context on the target platform, both implicitly through import lib and explicitly through LoadLibrary. Get closer to the metal, then add your managed/native transitional stuff back in. You can also in a pinch use Detours to intercept calls to LoadLibrary, grabbing that inner error code, actually you probably don't even need to go that far, debugger can cap this

Comment: @hacksalot I did this test. It works fine. The dll only fails to load when the API is called from .NET.

Comment: So the only piece you don't have is the internal LoadLibrary's failure code? Doesn't LoadLibrary do a `SetLastError`? Debugger can pick this up too. Weird, though.

Comment: @hacksalot LoadLibrary do calls SetLastError but there is no guarantee that the it will be the last error set. I will try it, though.

Answer (score 1):

Likely because the dll is depending on some files that are missing. Use [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and see what files it requires. Check on both systems. The tool will show you in red the missing files. Do not blindly copy the files.See what they are, what runtime or setup is required to deploy them, and deploy them properly.

Comment: Actually this is probably more practical advice

Comment: I used dependency walker and no files where missing in any of the platforms where the failure happened for any of the dlls in the dependency chain.

Comment: Then follow [Debugging LoadLibrary Failures](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/junfeng/2006/11/20/debugging-loadlibrary-failures/) steps and identify the cause.

Answer (score 0):

.Net applications can be built with AnyCPU as their target and run in both 64 and 32 bit modes, but if you choose AnyCPU for your target the operating system will choose one based on it's preference. What this can mean if you have native dependencies is that the library that you're depending on can't be loaded because you're running in the wrong bitness. If you can constrain the application to the bitness you're expecting it might work better.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The odd thing about this is that all assemblies are targeted for x86 during testing and the only Platform that fails is 32 bits Windows 7.

Comment: Have you tried using sysinternals process monitor before? It will tell you when an app tries to open a file and the search order. It may be that your OS just isn't looking in the right place, or that the file isn't registered

Comment: I have used it before but had forgotten about it. Thanks for the reminder. Will try that.